# useEffect triggers everything

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, use-effect

Hi just trying to learn about hooks inside a Next.JS project. Have implemented a useEffect to listen for scrolling behavior with the goal of displaying different content in a header is the page is scrolled.

```
const [ scrollY, setScrollY ] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
        const handleScroll = () => {
            setScrollY(window.scrollY);
        };
        handleScroll();
        
        window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
        };
    }, []);
```

Then i just have something like

`<div className={scrollY > 20 ? 'scrolled': null}>`

This works for its purpose but an unintended effect is that scrolling is now additionally triggering everything in the component, so for example if I have console.logs outwith the useEffect they would get triggered on every scroll of the page.  Is it possible to have my UE purely update the scrollY state?

Example of an issue would be:

```
const [ scrollY, setScrollY ] = useState(0);
const test = "test";
console.log(test);

useEffect(() => {
        const handleScroll = () => {
            setScrollY(window.scrollY);
        };
        handleScroll();
        
        window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
        };
    }, []);
```

Test would be logged repeatedly on every scroll.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve using scrollY? Maybe I can provide a better solution if I know what exactly you want to implement?

Comment: @ManishKumar my goal is to change the styling of an element when the page is scrolled.  I use it on several elements but an example would be to add a drop shadow under a fixed header.

Comment: Ok, In that case, you should not depend on scroll event as it will be fired a lot of time and hence the component state is updated resulting in the re-renders. To achieve this you can use the Intersection API.
Here is the link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Answer (score 0):

It will trigger many times,because every time you scroll,the function component would be called,and the view would update.

Comment: Yeah, I understand why its happening, i'm more wondering if there is an approach I could take to stop it from from happening. Sorry, maybe should have made the question clearer.

Comment: useCallback, and give the corrent deps.

Answer (score 0):

You use State in your Component. When you call the `setScrollY()`, you are updating the State, which triggers a re-render of your component.

If you want to use `console.log` to log the value of the `scrollY`, you could do it when you set `scrollY` instead of on each run. You should also ask yourself if `scrollY` needs to be stored as State, and if so, why.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest putting the header logic inside the scroll handler.

Like so:

```js
const [ isScrolled, setIsScrolled ] = useState(false);

...
const handleScroll = () => {
    if (window.scrollY > 20 && !isScrolled) {
        setIsScrolled(true);
    }

    if (window.scrollY <= 20 && isScrolled) {
        setIsScrolled(false);
    }
};
...

<MyComponent attribute={isScrolled && 'scrolled'} />
```

This will drastically reduce the amount of rerenders by setting the state whenever the scroll position meets the required point.